# Calling APIs in sequence with token in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to call 5 `APIs` in sequence after generating the token. i am using below `API` to generate `token`.

```
POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token
```

I will send `username` and `password` to get token in above API. Once token will be received I will have to use the `same token` to call below 5 `APIs` in sequence.
I will use `output` of one `API` and filter it and pick some values as an input to next `API`.

```
GET https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills

GET https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills/dynamicEntities

POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/v2/yyy

PATCH https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx

PUT https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/DONE
```

How can I `automate token generation` and the same `token` can be used in every `API call`. `token` will expire in every one hour. My only purpose is to automate above process somehow.
even smallest help would be highly appreciated. I could not get much material from google.

Comment: I have to create restclient either in nodejs or vanilla javascript. through postman I can consume all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *interceptors* feature in [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

**Example:**

```js
const axios = require('axios')

// Create new instances specifically for API calls
const apiFetcher = axios.create()

// Register new interceptor specifically for handling token generation
apiFetcher.interceptors.request.use((config) => {

  // this function will be run every time you make a request
  return (async () => {
    // You can prepare your token in here
    // example:

    // You can take an existing token or create a new token if it doesn't exist
    let token = await getToken()

    // Check if token expired. If yes, generate new token
    if (isExpired(token)) token = await generateNewToken()

    // Assign token to request header. You can put it anywhere.
    config.headers.Authentication = `bearer ${token}`

    // Return new config contain token
    return config
  })()
})

// Now, your token will be used every time you call to the API. And now 
// you don't need to handle the creation and checking of tokens manually. 
// the interceptors function will be triggered every time you call the API

apiFetcher.get('API 1')
apiFetcher.post('API 2')
apiFetcher.put('API 3')
apiFetcher.get('API 4')
// etc
```

More reference:
https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors